# audioElement.play(); is not working in new chrome

Tags: javascript, html, autoplay

I have external JavaScript file and I am testing it. All the codes run perfectly but the audio is not playing. I am just thinking that Chrome has changed its autoplay policies and this might be why my audio is not playing. I have read from this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) about this changes but I couldn't figure it out how I can get it done.

Here is just my simple JavaScript code

```
var audioElement = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3");
audioElement.play();
```

Is there anyone who can tell me how possibly I can play this audio (automatically) when the code runs?

Comment: You cannot automatically play audio elements without prior user interaction. That's just the way it is today.

Comment: @Terry is there any work around that fix this?

Comment: Nope. Otherwise we will be forever stuck with ads that autoplay audio on the go.